# Kafka Broker may not be available on 127.0.0.1:2181

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to run a kafka cluster with this command :

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic first_topic --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
```

and i get this as an error:

```
[2022-02-03 11:25:28,635] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:2181) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

So i tried to look at kafka_2.12-3.1.0\config\server.properties i have

> listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try this ```kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <topic_name> --create ```

Comment: --zookeeper is no longer supported so it's replace by --bootstrap-server

Comment: If Zookeeper isn't supported, why are you still trying to use port 2181 in your command as if it's a broker? That's not the port shown in your listeners...

Comment: i wanted to say that --zookeeper is replaced by --bootstrap-server

Comment: I understood what you meant, but you are still using the Zookeeper port in your command, rather than Kafka's 9092. I voted to close this question as a typo. Compare what you typed with https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: Thank you OneCricketeer you are right ! it works cool !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2181` is typically the port used by ZooKeeper. If you want to specify that, and you're not running Kafka in KRaft (zookeeper-less mode) then you need to do as @Umeshwaran said and use the `--zookeeper` argument.

However, you *can* use `--bootstrap-server`, but if you are doing so then specify the *broker* address and port, which from your listeners config is `9092`:

```
kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic first_topic --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
```

[This article](https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/blog/how-to-prepare-for-kip-500-kafka-zookeeper-removal-guide/) should clarify things.

Comment: Thank you Robin it works

Comment: Great. Feel free to mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Dude must have fallen off a cliff or something and could not mark this as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your zookeeper is not working ,I was facing the same issue but when I run the zookeeper with(I am using wsl)

"zookeeper-server-start.sh ~/kafka_2.13-3.3.1/config/zookeeper.properties"
command it starts working

I am running Kafka also if you don't how to run, use this command

"kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka_2.13-3.3.1/config/server.properties"

hint- modify kafka_2.13-3.3.1 this with the correct version of kafka you are using

Comment: He is passing Zookeeper address:port where Broker address:port is required by the command, you are talking different than expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i fixed that error log when I configured the bootstrap-servers into application.yml:

```
  spring:
    profiles: dev
    kafka:
      bootstrap-servers: 127.0.0.1:2181
```

Maybe the only line you need is bootstrap-servers: 127.0.0.1:2181